# Java swing components are got frozen

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, client-server

I'm making a server-client application project in netbeans. I made some Jpanel, and some other stuff (buttons, textfield, textarea, menu) on my JFrame with the netbeans gui builder.
When I push the new server button the whole JFrame and the all of its components are got frozen, but the server-client part is working on the background. I think there is a problem about the threads or something, 
but I've not really understood what i'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is likely that your server-client code is in fact ***not*** working in the background but instead working on the Swing event thread. You can test this you know with a [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) method: `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`

Also:

- Are you using a SwingWorker to do the background work?
- Are you doing any `join()` calls with a background thread?
- Are you waiting on a SwingWorkers `get()` method?

The details of your code will likely help us give you more specific advice. To learn what you're supposed to do, please read, [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I managed to find out my problem. I made a stupid mistake.
When I wanted to start the server thread I called the run method instead of the start.
thats why it got frozen. Nevertheless, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user1707095: my advice was then correct: by calling `run()` directly you're calling the long-running code on event thread as I suspected.